# Can I fine tune a pre-trained classification CNN like Resnet and Vgg19 to predict some angles in the images?

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Recently I modeled a horse in Blender and randomly changed the rotation of its head, neck and legs, and rendered many images to build a dataset.

After that I fine tuned resnet and vgg19 to predict the rotation of each part, but got a very poor performance. The loss dropped from 0.9 to 0.6 but didn't reach a low enough value, and the performance on validation set is very very poor.

**Here are some potential causes to that in my view:**

*1 Fine tuning classification models for this task is not suitable.*

*2 I slightly change the fully connected layers and add a tanh on it to predict the sin and cos of angles, then minimize the mean square error between predictions and ground truth. Tanh is not suitable for this task.*

Does any one have the experience of fine tune a model to predict the angles?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience of finetune a model to predict a angle. 
But for my object detection task experience, the task could do. Because in object detection, some output is position coordinates. And the polar coordinates and Rectangular coordinate system could Transform to each other by a matrix multiplication. So, you can try the method of of object detection.

Comment: Can I trained a end-to-end network to do the prediction? I mean, input the image, output the angles, without box regression?

Comment: Yes， you can try. There are a lot end-to-end network to prediction box regression. The one more task you should do is transform box regression to angles in CNN.

Comment: emmm, you misunderstood my words. I mean it is possible to directly predict the angles from images, without box regression, in other words, without knowing where the rotated objects are?